# ffmpeg HLS timing broken because of broken .ts file

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

So I've got .m3u8 file which looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:6.006,
seg-1-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:4.004,
seg-2-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:10.010,
eg-3-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:10.010,
seg-4-v1-a1.ts
#EXTINF:10.010,
seg-5-v1-a1.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

and I've got all the segment files in one folder.
The problem is that "seg-4-v1-a1.ts" is broken (only 5 MB where it should be 10MB) and when I try to transform them to an mp4 with the command `ffmpeg -i "M3U8URLS.mux" -c copy output.mp4`, I get a bad sync of the audio and the video.

The output of ffmpeg is

```
[hls,applehttp @ 000002e276a868a0] Opening 'crypto:seg-1-v1-a1.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 000002e276a868a0] Opening 'crypto:seg-2-v1-a1.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 000002e276a868a0] Opening 'crypto:seg-3-v1-a1.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 000002e276a868a0] Opening 'crypto:seg-4-v1-a1.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 00000204393ed020] PES packet size mismatch
[hls,applehttp @ 000002e276a868a0] Opening 'crypto:seg-5-v1-a1.ts' for reading
frame=35130 fps=1927 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1017088kB time=00:00:40.12 bitrate=5667.5kbits/s speed=80.6x
```

How can I tell ffmpeg that it should stay synced based on the #EXTINF info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must modify the playlist and set a #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY after the broken file.

Comment: After or before the broken file?

Comment: At the broken part, If the start of the file is missing, then before, if the end of the file is missing, then after.